# how to clear up all entries from solacache and also delete one entry(key) from solcache

Tags: caching, solace

We are using solace-cache/solcache in our project. In our dev environment its very difficult for us to go to solace admins to request for a cache refresh.

My question is:

Using the solace java API, is there a way we could clear up our entire solace cache instance and/or is there a way for us to delete specific keys already stored in the cache ?

If not, are there any simple commands that we could use to do this using the SEMP protocol without needing full admin rights to solace appliances?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

The easiest option is to actually request for a limited management account with only read/write permission on your message-vpn from your adminstrators.
Then, you can make use of the management tools such as SolAdmin to manage your VPN.

Failing that, this can be done by executing the a SEMP over message bus command.
Publish the following message to topic `#SEMP/<router name>/ADMIN/DISTRIBUTED-CACHE`

```
<rpc>
    <admin>
        <distributed-cache>
            <name>myDistributedCacheName</name>
            <vpn-name>myVpnName</vpn-name>
            <delete-messages>
                <topic>my/topic/name</topic>
            </delete-messages>
        </distributed-cache>
    </admin>
</rpc>
```

Wildcards can be specified in the topic string. For example, using a topic string of ">" will delete all messages in the cache.

Note that your message-vpn must be configured to:

- Allow SEMP over Message Bus
- Allow Admin Commands
- Allow Distributed Cache Commands

Details on enabling these features in your message-vpn can be found [here](https://docs.solace.com/SEMP/Using-Legacy-SEMP.htm#Configur).

Details on Publishing SEMP Requests over the Message Bus can be found [here](https://docs.solace.com/SEMP/Using-Legacy-SEMP.htm#Publishi2). Alternatively, refer to the SempGetOverMB.java sample that is provided with the Solace Java API.